# Exporting Monitoring Metrics Explorer results to CSV

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I am looking for a way to export the results from "Monitoring Metrics Explorer" CSV. I am using MQL to fetch required data. But I could not find options to export the data into a CSV file.

I tried visible options available in the Metrics Explorer interface. But no luck.
My expectation is that "Export to CSV" kind of option should have been there in the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvYPH.png)

Not sure if I am missing something here.

Regards,
Prasad.

Answer (score 1):

You save it to a dashboard, then in that chart in the dashboard you can Save as CSV

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).